# Possible issue with WAFileMetadataLibrary

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I was using WAFileMetadataLibrary and i found a possible issue with

```
addFileAt: aPath relativeToRootDirectory: relativeRootDirectory.
```

The problem i encountered is that some css with(../img/someImage.png) was getting pointed towards

`http://localhost:8080/files/img/someImage.png`

rather than

`http://localhost:8080/files/MyWAFileMetadataLibrary/img/someImage.png`

upon further looking into the code i found that in addFileAt: aPath relativeToRootDirectory: relativeRootDirectory.

there is a line

```
relativeFilepath := relativeFilepath replaceAll: pathSeparator  with:'/'.
```

here i found that the path with '\' (**im in windows**) will not be replaced with '/'.

so i had override and change the line to

```
relativeFilepath := relativeFilepath replaceAll: pathSeparator first with: $/.
```

which worked for me, and the calls from css got pointed to

`http://localhost:8080/files/MyWAFileMetadataLibrary/img/someImage.png`.

Could anyone in the community pls verify it and let me know if i am not further messing things up  , and if its ok, pls could you correct WAFileMetadaLibrary accordinly?

Answer (score 2):

I just checked and in Seaside 30 and Seaside 3.1 (using the Pharo CI server https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/).

In Seaside 3.1 the code is

```
addFileAt: aPath relativeToRootDirectory: relativeRootDirectory
| relativeFilepath pathSeparator |
relativeFilepath := aPath allButFirst: relativeRootDirectory size.
pathSeparator := GRPlatform current pathSeparator.

(relativeFilepath first = pathSeparator first) 
    ifTrue: [ relativeFilepath := relativeFilepath allButFirst ].

relativeFilepath := relativeFilepath replaceAll: pathSeparator first with: $/. 

self addFileNamed: relativeFilepath
    contents: (GRPlatform current 
            contentsOfFile: aPath
            binary: (self isBinaryAt: aPath))
```

Your fix looks good.

And indeed in Seaside 30

```
 relativeFilepath := relativeFilepath replaceAll: pathSeparator first with: '/'.
```

So you probably found a bug.